# Find length of a side from given mesurements

Tags: geometry

[image]
*Source: [gradestack.com](http://gradestack.com)*

This is a problem I am trying to solve for a long time. But still not able to proceed. After spending some time, I got a doubt whether this question is correct.

Because, in a rhombus, diagonals bisects each other. Here PA=PC. That means, P is the center point of diagonal AC. So PD must be equal to PB which is not the case. Why I am wrong here?

Please give pointers in how to solve this problem. thanks.

Comment: While $PA=PC$ is true, it doesn't follow that $P$ is the midpoint of $AC$. (Consider that one also has $AB=BC$ but $B$ isn't the midpoint.)

Comment: Nothing in the problem statement says that $P$ lies on $\overline{AC}$, only that it is equidistant from those two points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$PA=PC\implies P $ lies on the perpendicular bisector of the line $AC$. Proceed in the following way .

Suppose $Q$is the center of the rhombus.
$PB+PD=BD=10\implies  QD= 5 \\ AQ=\sqrt{PA^2-PQ^2}=\sqrt{5^2-3^2}=4\\ AD=\sqrt{AQ^2+QD^2}=\sqrt{41}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $P$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ and hence on $BD$. It does not lie on $AC$.

Let $\angle APB=\theta$. By the cosine rule $x^2=25+64-80\cos\theta=4+25+20\cos\theta$. So $5x^2=(89+4\cdot29)=205$, so $x=\sqrt{41}$.

[image]